# How can I use the pims.open() function under a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, subdirectory

I am running a piece of code (using trackpy and pims libraries) on all images in a given folder. Now I need to make a loop which will access all the folders in a given folder and then sequentially run the same code over all the files in each folder one-by-one and save the output. I could access all the folders in a given folder using the os library like so:

```
path = '/file_path'
for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in directories:
      print(os.path.join(root, subdirectory))
```

But if I try to add my code into this in which the first step is to open all the images in one specific folder using `pims.open()` it asks for the name of the folder to be specified that is it doesn't accept this code:

```
for name in directories:
variable = pims.open("name/*.jpg")
```

neither this:

```
for name in directories:
variable = pims.open("(os.path.join(name))/*.jpg")
```

The traceback I get is: This file does not exist.

Edit: As pointed out in the answers, I was referencing `name` as a string and not a variable but then when I followed

```
for name in directories:
        variable =pims.open(name +  '/*.jpg')
```

it is still unable to access all the .jpg files in the subfolders for my given folder. For example, right now I have just saved 5 .jpg images in one subfolder (subA) of a main folder (mainA). So the error I get now is: The file subA/*.jpg does not exist.

Comment: `"name/*.jpg"` is just a string. Did you mean to have the actual value of the variable `name` in the string? Look into Python string formatting for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try f-strings:

```
for name in directories:
    variable = pims.open(f"{os.path.join(name)}/*.jpg")
```

Comment: This way it is able to open the subfolder (let's call it subA) within the given folder (let's call it mainA) but earlier where I was able to access all jpg images in the folder subA using `"subA/*.jpg"` now it says the file subA/.*jpg does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by gshpychka you have a string `"name/*.jpg"`. The `name` in there is not referencing the variable but just part of that string.

```
for name in directories:
    variable = pims.open(name +  '/*.jpg')
```

Or you can use `f"{name}/*.jpg"` to tell python that it should substitute `{name}` with the content of the variable `name`. Starting the string with `f` enables that kind of behaviour(E.g. `f"here is {a} and {b}."` would replace `{a}` with the contents of variable a and `{b}` b with the contents of variable `b`). This has the advantage, that it also works the same with non-string types while for the simple `+` you would need to explicitly convert others (like e.g. numeric types) into string types.

```
for name in directories:
    variable = pims.open(f"{name}/*.jpg")
```

But you should probably use `os.path.join` as that reduces chances of errors a bit.

```
for name in directories:
    variable = pims.open(os.path.join(name, '*.jpg'))
```

you can have a look there:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

or

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/